# Ignore specific path when running setup:di:compile in Magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2, setup-di-compile, production-mode

Is there a additional command to add to `setup:di:compile` command to ignore a specific path compilation?

In Magento 2 this could be done with additional parameter `--exclude-pattern`, but in Magento 2.2 no more.

> I need to set **production mode** and there is a module that is
>   blocking `setup:di:compile`. I tried to disable module but did not
>   work.